# How to create a new database from a backup in mysql

Tags: mysql, backup, database-restore

I used MySQL enterprise backup but I have to restore one table now.
I don't want to touch my existing tables butI want to restore one database into a new databases so I can view the old values and take only couple thigs out of it.

I have apply-log to the database that I want to restore.
then I created a new database called XY and I placed all the files that were generated after the "appy-log" operation into the XY folder into mysql data file,.

I do see all the tables but when I try to query any of them I get error "table does not exists"

how can I get mysql to read the restored files into a new table without causing more issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just move files around under the data directory and expect InnoDB to notice them.

InnoDB maintains a "data dictionary" which can be thought of like a table of contents for a book. This is how InnoDB knows what tables exist. The data dictionary is updated by DDL statements such as CREATE, ALTER, DROP, RENAME. But it's not updated if you physically move a file into the datadir.

A method to import a table from a MySQL Enterprise Backup is documented here: [Backing Up and Restoring a Single .ibd File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.9/en/partial.restoring.single.html).

MySQL 5.6 introduced some new flexibility with their [transportable tablespace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html) feature.

Note that both of these methods are for importing *one table at a time*. There is no solution for importing a whole database.

Ultimately, it would be a lot easier for you to restore your backup to a separate instance of MySQL, and then access the few things you need to. A good tool to help you set up a temporary instance of MySQL is [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/).